# Why doesn't this code work (Please See Details)?

Tags: c++, winapi, runtime-error

I have written the following code (x64 VS 2015):

```
typedef void(__stdcall *foo)(void* v);
HMODULE hmod = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
foo f = (foo) GetProcAddress(hmod, "_foo0");
f(0);
```

`foo0` is defined as:

```
extern "C" void __stdcall foo0(void* v){int a = 0;}
```

I have disabled all optimizations and security checks.

What I want the code to do is to find the address of the `foo0` and then call it.
For some weird reason, calling `GetLastError()` after `GetModuleHandle()` returns `0x00000032` which means `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`, but it does return some nonzero value which I assume is the handle to the executable. `GetProcAddress()` returns `0x0000000000000000` and a `GetLastError()` call after it returns `0x0000007f` which means `ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND`, but I defined the proc!

Why is this happening? Is `GetProcAddress()` not supposed to be used with `GetModuleHandle()`?

Comment: Why are you reading `GetLastError()` after `GetModuleHandle()` if `GetModuleHandle()` succeeded?

Comment: [Format of a C Decorated Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7kb4e2f.aspx): *"Note that in a 64-bit environment, functions are not decorated."*

Comment: `GetLastError` should only be used after you have determined that something has failed, and if that "something" is documented to return further information that way. At all other times, its result is useless.

Comment: Stepping back, what problem are you trying to solve. I'm prepared to bet that this isn't the solution.

Comment: @molbdnilo: *"Failure"* is no prerequisite to calling `GetLastError`. You can call `GetLastError` after a call to [CreateMutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411.aspx) succeeded, for example.

Comment: Besides, what's wrong with `foo f = &foo0;`?

Comment: @IInspectable There are a few (rare) exceptions to the "failure principle", but `CreateMutex` is not one of them. (I probably should have written "and/or"  instead of "and", but it's too late to edit.)

Comment: @IInspectable Failure is a pre-requisite in the case of GetModuleHandle and GetProcAddress.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I wasn't referring to the APIs called in this question. I was referring to an inaccurate comment. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @molbdnilo This is just a test, foo0 will be injected at runtime.

Comment: @GeekusMaximus You seem very confused. Do you understand how `GetProcAddress` works? Do you know how it maps from a name to an address?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I was suspecting that `GetProcAddress` uses the exports table to map identifiers to addresses, but I decided to try anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code fails because `GetProcAddress` requires the supplied symbol to have been exported from the module in question. That is, the symbol must have been listed in the PE module's export table. You do not export the symbol, and so `GetProcAddress` cannot find it. Hence `GetProcAddress` returns `NULL`. If you wish to use `GetProcAddress` then you must export the symbol. Either by naming it in a .def file, or by using `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Some other comments:

1. You appear to have a mismatch of calling conventions, `stdcall` and `cdecl`.
2. You don't perform any error checking. For these particular function you need to check the return value. If that indicates that the function has failed, then call `GetLastError` for extended error information.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void foo0(void* v) { int a = 0; }
```

and:

```
foo f = (foo)GetProcAddress(hmod, "foo0");
                                  ^^~~~ no need for underline
```

as to your GetLastError issue, I am not sure about it - I suppose it might be some random value.

Comment: The OP is also mixing calling conventions; you should point this out as well.

Comment: @GeekusMaximus Your pointer is stdcall and your function is cdecl. Once you do get your hands on the `foo0()` pointer any attempt to call it will crash. Keep an eye on the calling convention.

Comment: I plan on injecting foo0 at runtime, so ` __declspec(dllexport)` wont work.

Comment: @GeekusMaximus: That doesn't make sense. If you are injecting a binary image (DLL), `__declspec(dllexport)` will work. If you misrepresented your objective, and meant to write that the code is **generated** at runtime, then you already have the address. andlabs: There is only one calling convention in 64-bit Windows. Since there is only one to choose from, you will always pick the right one, if only by coincidence.